# Query AdminDirectory.Users.get using the values of object

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working with Google Apps Script and so far I'm able to query a user details given its email:

```
var result = AdminDirectory.Users.get('some.email@domain.com', {viewType:'domain_public'});
Logger.log(result.externalIds);
```

The result in this case is limited to the object 'externalIds' and reads:

```
{customType=Auth ID, type=custom, value=abc123}
```

Now, is there a way to take the value from the response and query for the email address?
Something like:

```
var result = AdminDirectory.Users.get({customType: 'Auth ID', type: 'custom', value: 'abc123'}, {viewType:'domain_public'});
Logger.log(result.emails);
```

To get something like:

```
{address=some.email@domain.com, primary=true}
```

And further more, can I get only the value 'address' from the emails object?

Thanks you all.

Edit: Well just found out I can get the specific field address by doing:

```
Logger.log(result.emails[0].address);
```